# Problems with symfony homepage in routing.yml

Tags: php, routes, symfony-1.4

I'm following the Jobeet tutorial on symfony 1.4 website and i'm having some problems in routing.yml.

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/04

I already created the jobeet module and specified it in my routing.yml. When i go to the frontend_dev, it works perfectly. However, when going through index.php, it shows the default symfony homepage. As if i hadn't changed the routing.

Are there different routing for development and production? What can be causing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you cleaned your cache? Changes in routing.yml will only take effect on production after clearing the cache.

```
php symfony cache:clear
```

The reason it worked when you used `frontend_dev.php` is that this loads the application using the `dev` environment.  In dev mode, Symfony checks to see if configuration files were modified since the last request and will override the cached versions if they have changed.

Comment: Lol, you mean to tell me the good ol "did you clear cache?" solution actually worked?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a mod_rewrite issue.

What you will need to do, is ensure that your apache instance has mod_rewrite enabled.

Typically, what you would do is put the .htaccess file that is found in your /symfonyproject/web folder, and copy it into your web root folder.